# Gameshow JavaScript spinner can't find Value

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get results of the spinner. After 6 hours of debugging and all sorts of math attempts I can't seem to find out how to get the value of the spinner with each spin. What DIV does it land on?!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMrOPe

Initially I thought the following algorithm would work.

```
total_rotations = Get Total Degrees in rotations (including what was done historically.
total_rotations /  360 = _total_rotations_of_a_circle
value_to_subtract = Take the absolute value of _total_rotations_of_a_circle * 360
left_over_value_in_Degree = total_rotations - value_to_subtract
left_over_value_in_Degree/60 = result.
```

This algorithm only works SOMETIMES. I just am not sure how to do this, any tips would help.

The aoY variable was presented by the original developer, but I don't know how to use that value to find the actual div its pointing to. What math do I need here?

```
$('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;

        var c = 0;
        var n = 700;    
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            c++;                
            if (c === n) { 
                clearInterval(interval);                
            }   

            var aoY = t.offset().top;
            $("#txt").html(aoY);
            console.log(aoY);

            /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
            each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
            So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
            that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
            exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
            if(aoY < 23.89){
                console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                }, 100);    
            }
        }, 10);

        $('#inner-wheel').css({
            'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
        });

        noY = t.offset().top;

    });
});
```

Comment: Try `Math.ceil(((total_rotations+30) % 360) / 60)`, so if `(total_rotations+30) % 360` is say 267, then the result will be 5, so the fifth sector (numbering anti–clockwise) will be under the pointer (starting numbering at 1, use *Math.floor* to start numbering at zero). There is an offset of 30 degrees because the pointer starts in the middle of the first sector.

Comment: Note that you have `(360 - 1 + 1)` which is just `360`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The formula RobG proposed is correct:

`Math.ceil((( totalDegree + 30 ) % 360) / 60)`

Something you also have to take into account is the fact that the offset changes for every consecutive plays. In order to deal with that, you can simply use this formula:

`offset = extraDegree MOD 60`

You can then replace the number 30 in the function by the offset variable:

`Math.ceil((( totalDegree + offset ) % 360) / 60)`

[See this fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJbyzP)

Comment: I'm not sure the offset changes, I spun the wheel quite a few times using offset 30 and it didn't seem to be accumulating any error. It even came up with a result of 0 a couple of times and sat exactly on the boundary of sectors 1 and 6. I think the OP should randomly select the sector, then work out how far to spin based on `x` rotations plus `y*60` degrees, then have an easing to slow the spin as it approaches the target. The selector then sits in the center every time.

Comment: It seems that transform:rotate is an absolute rotation, not relative. If the image is rotated 30 degrees, setting the rotation to 30 degrees again doesn't rotate it to 60 degrees, it stays at 30 degrees. In the OP (well, linked code), *totalDegree* is always initialised as a multiple of 1800 plus some random value, so the offset doesn't accumulate.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that was my error. To redeem myself, I found a use to my offset variable [See this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwQva)